# Slow network copy in only one direction

Tags: windows-networking

I have a Windows network with several computers and mobile devices on it.  Everything is working fine except between one desktop and one laptop.  The problem is that the laptop is nearly unable to copy files from the desktop to the laptop.  This connection issue is limited to **only** that scenario.  It's probably easiest if I list off the scenarios that work/don't work:

```
Desktop writes to laptop => normal speeds
Desktop reads or copies from laptop => normal speeds
Laptop writes to desktop => normal speeds
Laptop reads or copies from desktop => SLOW
All other devices => normal speeds
```

All of the normal speeds on the network are at least 1-2MB/s, usually much greater.  The laptop is able to download from the internet at MB/s levels as well.  When the desktop initiates a copy to the laptop, the speed is high.  But if the laptop initiates the copy (file moving in the same direction as before), it runs at 100KB/s or less.

This problem manifested itself a few months ago, and I eventually did a format/reinstall on both machines and the problem went away.  Now, after about a month since the reinstalls, it is beginning to happen again.  Any ideas for fixing this or what in the world would cause such a lopsided speed problem in the first place?

Comment: How are the PC and Laptop connected? 'Network Location shortcut', 'FTP'...?

Comment: Mapped network drive, for the most part.  Both machines are running Win7x64 (Home for the laptop, Pro for the desktop).

Comment: OK, I suggest you try connecting with FTP [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client) and see if that makes any difference

Comment: I'm not running an FTP server on the desktop, though.  Also, that doesn't really solve the problem, especially for trying to manipulate files directly or stream videos from the desktop (which is how I actually first noticed it, though it happens with any file type when reading or copying).  Right now, if I need something on the laptop, I remote to the desktop and start the copy from there, since that still works.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior can have a lot of causes, like virus scanner, notify change problems and network problems.

To track it down I would create a bunch of testfiles and use always the same files for the tests. I would always compare these copies with a workstion working fast and the one working slow.

**Is the speed slower with a lot of small files (< 1000 bytes) using file explorer?**
So you may have a problem with the file opens, may be caused by a virus scanner ore the general disk access.

**Is the speed *faster* with a lot of small files (< 1000 bytes) using xcopy in cmd.exe an no explorer opened?**
This looks like a [notify change problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/openspecification/archive/2013/03/27/smb-2-x-and-smb-3-0-timeouts-in-windows.aspx).

**Is the copy of big files fast?**
Check the network using [netio.exe](http://www.ars.de/ars/ars.nsf/docs/netio).

Other ways to check it are the use of microsoft [netmon](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) or microsoft [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). In the netmon you can see if there are gaps between the packets. In procmon you can see the duration of the various file operation.